# How to create a numpy array of N numbers of the same value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is surely an easy question:

How does one create a numpy array of N values, all the same value?

For instance, `numpy.arange(10)` creates 10 values of integers from 0 to 9.

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I would like to create a numpy array of 10 values of the same integer,

```
array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

Comment: `numpy.reapeat(3, 10)`...

Comment: ...or `np.full(10, 3)`.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary you certainly mean `repeat()` (with only one 'a') ;)

Comment: @ajcr to be closer to OP question I would suggest to constrain type of the array: `np.full(10, 3, dtype=np.int)` otherwise it may be float result...

Comment: Nice functions, I didn't know them, I always used something like `np.ones(10) * 3` .

Comment: In case you use, @AshwiniChaudhary 's response in the comment, please note it is numpy.repeat(3,10). There is a mistype there and you will get an error.

Answer (score 37):

Use [`numpy.full()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html):

```py
import numpy as np

np.full(
  shape=10,
  fill_value=3,
  dtype=np.int
)
    
> array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

Answer (score 7):

Very easy
1)we use arange function :-

```
arr3=np.arange(0,10)
output=array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

2)we use ones function whose provide 1 and after we will do multiply 3 :-

```
arr4=np.ones(10)*3
output=array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.])
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative (faster) way to do this would be with [`np.empty()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) and [`np.fill()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html):

```
import numpy as np

shape = 10
value = 3


myarray = np.empty(shape, dtype=np.int)
myarray.fill(value)
```

**Time comparison**

The above approach on my machine executes for:

```
951 ns ± 14 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

vs using `np.full(shape=shape, fill_value=value, dtype=np.int)` executes for:

```
1.66 µs ± 24.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

vs using `np.repeat(value, shape)` executes for:

```
2.77 µs ± 41.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

vs using `np.ones(shape) * value` executes for:

```
2.71 µs ± 56.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I find it to be consistently a little bit quicker.

Answer (score 5):

I realize it's not using numpy, but this is very easy with base python.

```
data = [3]*10
print(data)
> [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is worked well in my python version (Python 3.9.6).

```
import numpy as np 
np.array([3]*10)

output:
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, this is the easiest way:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(0, 11)
arr[:] = 0

output:
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).